# Hadoop Mapper: Class or Interface

Tags: hadoop

I am a bit confused about the basic Mapper structure in Hadoop.  On the web, many example implementations use Mapper as a class and thus their classes extend Mapper.  As far as I have seen, which is Hadoop 19, Mapper is an interface.  What happened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the old API, Mappers implemented an interface as you might expect.

When the big overhaul came around, they decided to change it to a fully fledged class so that it can act as the often needed Identity Mapper if used as is, or extended for your own implementations.

It's just a matter of whether you're using the old or new API for your project, you shouldn't mix - `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` is the old API, `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` is the new.

Comment: very good it might change back to interface in next version :\ Can I know from which version this has been changed?